# SQL Server Managed Backup to Azure

Tags: azure-blob-storage, database-backups, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to backup SQL Server (Local) to Azure Blob Storage. I have created the SAS Credential

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://xxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/yyyyyyyy]   
WITH IDENTITY = 'Shared Access Signature',  
SECRET = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
```

In SQL Server, while trying to enable the Backup for server using this command

```
USE msdb;  
GO  

EXEC msdb.managed_backup.sp_backup_config_basic   
     @enable_backup =1,   
     @database_name = 'TempDB',  
     @container_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/yyyyyyyy',   
     @retention_days = 30
GO
```

I get this error:

> Msg 45207, Level 17, State 17, Procedure managed_backup.sp_add_task_command, Line 102 [Batch Start Line 19]
> The operation failed because of an internal error. The argument must not be empty string.
> Parameter name: sasToken Please retry later.
>
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.AssertNotNullOrEmpty(String paramName, String value)
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials..ctor(String sasToken)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.SmartAdmin.SmartBackupAgent.FileService.VerifyContainerURL(String containerURL, SqlConnection conn)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.SmartAdmin.SmartBackupAgent.SmartBackup.ConfigureDbOrInstance(SmartBackupConfigParameters config, LogBaseService jobLogger, SqlConnection conn)

If we change the `@enable_backup` to "0", the query executes correctly.

I have tried re-creating the SAS key, it doesn't work.

PS: I'm currently using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Try with these steps

**1)** Create a SQL Server credential using a shared access signature.
To create a SQL Server credential, follow these steps:

- Connect to SQL Server Management Studio.
- Open a new query window and connect to the SQL Server instance of the
  database engine in your on-premises environment.
- In the new query window,  execute the following script .

  > USE master   CREATE CREDENTIAL
  > "https://.blob.core.windows.net/"
  > //this name must match the container path, start with https and must
  > not contain a forward slash at the end WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS
  > SIGNATURE'    //this is a mandatory string and should not be changed
  > , SECRET = 'sharedaccesssignature'    //this is the shared access
  > signature key   GO

Example:

```
 USE master  
    CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://msfttutorial.blob.core.windows.net/containername] 
    WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'   
    , SECRET = 'sharedaccesssignature' 
    GO
```

- To see all available credentials, you can run the following statement
  in a query window connected to your instance:

`SELECT * from sys.credentials`

**2)** Create backup .Modify the URL appropriately for your storage account name and the container and then execute this script.

```
//To permit log backups, before the full database backup, modify the database to use the full recovery model.  
USE master;  
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2016  
   SET RECOVERY FULL;  
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2016   
   TO URL = 'https://<mystorageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<mystorageaccountcontainername>/AdventureWorks2016_onprem.bak
```

**3)**  Open Object Explorer and connect to Azure storage using your storage account and account key. Expand Container verify that the backup  appears in this container.

[image]

For more details refer these links  [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-use-azure-blob-storage-service-with-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#2---create-a-sql-server-credential-using-a-shared-access-signature)  and [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=tsql)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has experienced the similar issue with SQL Server, an update may solve your problem.

> **Symptoms**
>
> Assume that you disable "Allow Blob Public Access" on a storage account. In this situation, when you enable a managed or automated backup in Microsoft SQL Server 2016 or 2017, you receive the following error message:
> **"SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure cannot configure the database 'DatabaseName' because a container URL was either not provided or invalid. It is also possible that your SAS credential is invalid."**
>
> **Resolution**
>
> This problem is fixed in the following cumulative update for SQL
> Server:
>
> - Cumulative Update 23 for SQL Server 2017
> - Cumulative Update 16 for SQL Server 2016 SP2

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4589360-fix-error-when-you-enable-managed-or-automated-backup-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-if-allow-blob-public-access-is-disabled-on-a-storage-account-d2315f8d-6a38-5d6c-6f02-3ab14c4b34cf